# クエリパラメター無しのURLにアクセスしたら、自動的にクエリパラメタを付加したURLに飛ばしたい。

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess

■実現したいこと（概要）：
クエリパラメター無しのURLにアクセスしたら、自動的にクエリパラメタを付加したURLに飛ばしたい。

■実現したいこと（詳細）：
１．現在、クエリパラメターを使って、DB連携で表示させるようなプログラムを
作成している。

２．具体的には、　　
http://◎◎◎.php?lan=en

であり、この場合、

◎◎◎.phpのプログラムの中で、

DBから、「lan=en、即ち言語がenglish」のものを抽出して、
表示させています。

３．当然のことながら、
単純に、クエリパラメター無しの
http://◎◎◎.phpにアクセスした場合には、
正常な表示がなされません。

４．やりたいこと：

具体的には、
http://◎◎◎.phpへのアクセスがあった場合に、

自動的に、
http://◎◎◎.php&lan=en
　
という具合に、クエリパラメターを付加して表示させたい。
.htaccessへ記載すればいいのでしょうか？

（追加の質問）
・.htaccessに記載する方法の場合、SEO対策的には有効な方法と考えられるの
でしょうか？
　
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/134181

Comment: 解決しました！
.htaccessファイルを使うことはせず、isset関数を使うことで、解決しました

■結論
phpファイルの、最初の行で、
<?php 
$lan = isset($_GET['lan']) ? $_GET['lan'] : 'en';
?>
を記載

■コードの説明
・isset関数を使うことによってクエリパラメターチェック
・三項演算子を使ってすっきりしたコードに

■PHP動作の流れ
◎パターン１
http://◎◎◎.php?lan=en
でアクセスされた場合は、isset関数を使うことによって、クエリパラメターをチェックし、$_GET['lan']があるので、$lan＝$_GET['lan']として処理が進む。つまり、これまで通り
http://◎◎◎.php?lan=enのURLとして表示

◎パターン２
http://◎◎◎.php
でアクセスされた場合は、isset関数を使うことによって、クエリパラメターをチェックし、$_GET['lan']がないので、内部的に、$lan＝'en';として、値を代入

この場合、URLとして表示されるのは、
http://◎◎◎.phpですが、

内部的には、
http://◎◎◎.php?lan=enにアクセスされた場合と
同じ処理

Comment: 自己回答ができるので、コメントではなく回答をお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

解決しました！
.htaccessファイルを使うことはせず、isset関数を使うことで解決しました

■結論
phpファイルの最初の行で以下のように記載。

```
<?php 
$lan = isset($_GET['lan']) ? $_GET['lan'] : 'en';
?>
```

■コードの説明
・isset関数を使うことによってクエリパラメターチェック
・三項演算子を使ってすっきりしたコードに

■PHP動作の流れ
◎パターン１
`http://example.com/XXX.php?lan=en`

でアクセスされた場合は、isset関数を使うことによってクエリパラメターをチェックし、`$_GET['lan']`があるので、`$lan＝$_GET['lan']`として処理が進む。
つまり、これまで通り`http://example.com/XXX.php?lan=en`のURLとして表示

◎パターン２

`http://example.com/XXX.php`
でアクセスされた場合は、isset関数を使うことによって、クエリパラメターをチェックし、`$_GET['lan']`がないので、内部的に、`$lan＝'en';`として値を代入

この場合、URLとして表示されるのは`http://example.com/XXX.php`ですが、
内部的には、`http://example.com/XXX.php?lan=en`にアクセスされた場合と同じ処理

---

この投稿は [@きむちゃん さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/45435/%e3%82%af%e3%82%a8%e3%83%aa%e3%83%91%e3%83%a9%e3%83%a1%e3%82%bf%e3%83%bc%e7%84%a1%e3%81%97%e3%81%aeurl%e3%81%ab%e3%82%a2%e3%82%af%e3%82%bb%e3%82%b9%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-%e8%87%aa%e5%8b%95%e7%9a%84%e3%81%ab%e3%82%af%e3%82%a8%e3%83%aa%e3%83%91%e3%83%a9%e3%83%a1%e3%82%bf%e3%82%92%e4%bb%98%e5%8a%a0%e3%81%97%e3%81%9furl%e3%81%ab%e9%a3%9b%e3%81%b0%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84#comment47570_45435) を元にコミュニティwikiとして投稿しました。